# how to create a 3d hill visualisation in three.js for my data visualisation

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am new to 3d Visualizations, I want to create a visualization application that has a 3d Hill representation of my data. So when the user slices a surface horizontally, can get all the data with values represented by height. I am planning to do it using three.js. webgl. I have no clue, from where to start. Little guidance would really help a lot.

Thanks & Regards,
Keerthika.K

Comment: This could help: http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/10/terrain-building-with-threejs.html

Comment: Also this: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_terrain_dynamic.html

Comment: hi thanks, i would go through it and work on it.

Comment: Hi, I want to create a structure like a hill or a 3d cone , so that my data would be mapped to a slice of the structure according to the height. Suppose if user slices the structure horizontally that plane should project all the ids(from data) with similar values mapped to that plane's height. @ user880772 . I have been going through the tutorials, but am not able to understand , what to use to create this. some guidance would really help me. thanks and regards, keerthika.

Comment: http://acko.net/blog/making-mathbox/  . I have found this demo. the second figure in the page. I want to  develop something like that

Comment: There you go, that link is basically a tutorial for doing what you want. The author even linked to his library at the end of his blog post: https://github.com/unconed/MathBox.js

Comment: Hi, Wanted to know if there is anyway that the 3d figures like sphere ... etc can take my own data values to be binded in to the figures.